# integration tests - redux/react + nock.js

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, nock

I have no clue how to find a way to write this integration test.
I am using enzyme for mocking react components, jest for testing and nock for mocking axios api calls.

So far I created test which simulate clicking on button and I would like to mock the api call.

In the internet there is no much help.

My test:

```
 it('Should invoke clear action and clear the group', (done) => {
    // GIVEN
    const clearButtonComponent = wrapper.find('[id="123"]');
    nock('http://localhost:8080')
      .intercept('/path/api/brum/123/group', 'DELETE')
      .reply(200, {
        status: 200,
        message: 'cleared',
      });
    const service = new myService();

    // WHEN
    clearButtonComponent.first().simulate('click');
    const result = Promise.resolve(service.clearGroup(123));

    // THEN
    expect(result).toEqual({ x: 'x' }); // I know it's not what I expect
    wrapper.update();
    done(); 
  });
```

async action redux:

```
export const clearGroup = id=> (dispatch, getState) => {
  myService.clearGroup(id)
    .then(() => {
        return dispatch(getGroup(id))
    });
};
```

method in myService:

```
  clearGroup(id) {
    return this._delete(`/${id}/group`);
  }
```

of course path is more complex but my service extends base service which has this base url.

Can anybody tell me how to mock it to let code goes further?

It still complain that id is undefined - look like nock does not mock it.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop nock (I try to only use it for testing clients these days) and mock `myService` with jest.

I don't use axios, so haven't used this, but it might do the trick.. https://github.com/knee-cola/jest-mock-axios.

Otherwise you could look at writing your own mock.. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

Comment: lecstor, thanks for answer. Problem is I can not install any different dependencies. So the solution can be to make a mock of my service and then mockImplementation on it? :) Regards

Comment: yup, shouldn't be too hard, though we can't see enough of myService to know for sure.